# What is the font used by Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, kubuntu, fonts

I have `Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer` installed on my `Kubuntu 20.04.5` OS. When I want to uninstall an old kernel it gives me an unreadable output ( see picture ).
[image: unreadable output] 
I think it uses a font that I have not installed. Does anybody knows what font it uses? So I can install the font and make the output readable. I have searched for an answer with good old Dr. Google, but all the pages I looked at don't answer my question. 
The program is usable, but obviously I want to be able to read the output.
The kernel I am running is `5.15.0.57.63`. 
This page (https://trendoceans.com/install-mainline-kernel-in-ubuntu/) shows the output like it should be. [image: output according webpage]
Trying Rubo77's answer gives me this output:

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ LANG=C ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer.sh
ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer.sh: command not found
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo LANG=C ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer.sh
[sudo] password for patrick: 
sudo: ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer.sh: command not found
patrick@Lappy:~$
```

My system:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-57-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing it again.

Comment: Doesnt work. It remains the same.

Comment: I see you are using a non-English locale.  This will sound like a stupid question, but have you tried switching your GUI language to English for the tool, then switched back afterwards?  It's possible it's a localization issue that is due to the locale you're using, as well as a 'font' issue.  It's impossible, however, to ID what 'font' is needed to display certain characters for different locales though.

Answer (score 0):

start the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer from the console prepending a switch to english like this:

```
LANG=C ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer.sh
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a suggestion, because I cannot test it.

I use `aptik`, a program developed by the same person that developed `ukuu`.

Mainline Kernel Installer is forked from `ukuu`.

I had the same font problem with `aptik`. To fix it, I installed the `fonts-liberation2` package.

Consider giving that package a try. If it does not work, please comment, and I will delete this suggestion/answer.